# Textarea removes data from db

Tags: php

i want to create a textarea, which will store information already inserted into the database and can be updated by a user but everytime i add  elements to the query it removes the already inserted data. But when i add  elements to the query, it keeps the data intact.

here is the code that keeps the data

```
<input name="mobile" type="text" class="field span6" rows="6" placeholder="Mobile" value="<?php echo !empty($mobile)?$mobile:'';?>"/>
```

and here is the code that removes it

```
<textarea name="mobile" type="text" class="field span6" rows="6" placeholder="Mobile" value="<?php echo !empty($mobile)?$mobile:'';?>"></textarea>
```

i am really puzzled as to why the textarea elements removes the data, keeping the textarea elements with the data still in tact will be a great help.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the PHP code to your question, please?

Comment: This also seems a bit redundant to me - `<?php echo !empty($mobile)?$mobile:'';?>`.  Would this not suffice? `<?php echo $mobile;?>`?

Comment: @Buggabill `echo $mobile;` generates a warning when `$mobile` is not set, but `!empty($mobile)?$mobile:'';` won't

Answer (score 1):

You are mis-using the `textarea` tag. Unlike `input`s it requires an opening and closing tag with the value of the textarea defined *between the tags* rather than through a `value` attribute.

Try:

```
<textarea 
      name="mobile" 
      class="field span6" 
      rows="6" 
      placeholder="Mobile"><?php echo !empty($mobile)?$mobile:'';?></textarea>
```

Also, unless you're checking the value of `$mobile` elsewhere, I'd recommend outputting it with `htmlentities()` to prevent HTML injection.

Comment: thank you so much, i was stumped on this for a while and cheers for explaining why